# How to find minimum, select the corresponding values, copy and paste the values to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Following is my problem description

```
      A    B    C    D     
   1  H1   H2   H3   H4   
   2  1    3    4    2      
   3  2    4    1    8     
   4  3    1    6    1       
   5  4    2    8    5
```

First row has the headings. Column A has the serial number of the table. Columns B, C, and D are values coming out from some calculations. I want to write a VBA code such that the code finds the minimum value in the Column D, selects all the corresponding values of the row, copies and pastes just the values in a sheet named NewSheet.

For the given case above, the VBA code should identify that the Cell D4 has the minimum value, it should select the corresponding values in row 4 (from cells B4, C4 and D4), copy these selected values and paste the values in the cells P2,Q2 and R2 of 'NewSheet'.

Since I am just a beginner, it will be highly appreciated if the responder can provide some comments that will help me to understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
Option Explicit ' Forces you to declare variables. Helps prevent stupid mistakes.

Sub Rabbit()

' Declare variables. Can also spread this throughout your code...
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range
Dim varData As Variant
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim iMinH4 As Long
Dim dblMinH4 As Double
Dim shtNew As Worksheet

' Where to get the data from (H1...H4 headers not included here)
Set rngData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(4, 4)

' Get all data from sheet at once. Faster than interrogating sheet multiple times.
varData = rngData

' Get first entry. This is the minimum so far, by definition...
iMinH4 = 1
dblMinH4 = varData(1, 4)
' Go through all other entries to see which is minimum.
For iCounter = LBound(varData, 1) +1 To UBound(varData, 1) ' +1 since first entry already checked
    If varData(iCounter, 4) < dblMinH4 Then
        ' This is the minimum so far.
        dblMinH4 = varData(iCounter, 4)
        iMinH4 = iCounter
    Else
        ' This is not the minimum.
        ' Do nothing.
    End If
Next iCounter

' If creating new sheet is necessary, uncomment this:
'Set shtNew = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
'shtNew.Name = "NewSheet"

' Where should the values go?
Set shtNew = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheet")
Set rngTarget = shtNew.Range("P2:R2")

' Copy the values over to NewSheet.
rngData.Cells(iMinH4, 1).Resize(1, 3).Copy rngTarget

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

This macro can be improved by writing a function that returns a column in a specified worksheet based on the column header. Then you would not have to hardcode the column numbers 4 and 16.

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim yourWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim searchArea As Range
Dim searchResult As Range
Dim yourWorkbook As String
Dim rowMinimum As Long
Dim minimumValue As Long
Dim columnSearch As Integer
Dim columnNew As Integer

columnSearch = 4
columnNew = 16

yourWorkbook = [workbook name]

Set yourWorksheet = Workbooks(yourWorkbook).Worksheets([worksheet name])
Set newSheet = Workbooks(yourWorkbook).Worksheets("NewSheet")

'Select all the cells in the column you want to search down to the first empty
'cell.
Set searchArea = yourWorksheet.Range(yourWorksheet.Cells(2, columnSearch), _
yourWorksheet.Cells(yourWorksheet.Cells(2, columnSearch).End(xlDown).Row, _
columnSearch))

'Determine the minimum value in the column.
minimumValue = Application.Min(searchArea)

'Find the row that contains the minimum value.
Set searchResult = yourWorksheet.Columns(columnSearch).Find(What:=minimumValue, _
After:=yourWorksheet.Cells(1, columnSearch), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)

'Store the row that contains the minimum value in a variable.
rowMinimum = searchResult.Cells.Row

'Copy the other cells in the row containing the minimum value to the new
'worksheet.
yourWorksheet.Range(yourWorksheet.Cells(rowMinimum, 1), _
yourWorksheet.Cells(rowMinimum, columnSearch - 1)).Copy _
Destination:=newSheet.Cells(2, columnNew)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Strcompnice..... i will be using your code in some way or the other... so wanted to say you thanks.... :-)

Comment: No problem. I discovered some errors when testing the macro in Excel, so I updated the code.

Comment: @strcompnice I was getting error in the code that has the following content " yourWorkbook = [workbook name]

Set yourWorksheet = Workbooks(yourWorkbook).Worksheets([worksheet name])
Set newSheet = Workbooks(yourWorkbook).Worksheets("NewSheet")"
Though I am trying to name my worksheet as DynamicArray2 I am not able to run the code. Any suggestions for getting it to run?

Comment: yourWorkbook should contain the name of your workbook. So for instance if the name of your workbook is TableData.xls, then the code should be yourWorkbook = "TableData.xls". The name of each worksheet can be found in the tabs at the bottom of the Excel window. So if the name of the worksheet with the data is DynamicArray2, the code should be Set yourWorksheet = Workbooks(yourWorkbook).Worksheets("DynamicArray2").

Comment: @strcompnice, Thanks a lot.... I pretty much understand your code and have used it with modifications for my work.... thanks a lot for the awesome help... best wishes... Josh

Comment: @strcompnice, What changes do I need to do the code to make it run when I have values in decimals in column four. For example if I have a value of 1.1 in cell D4 then what modifications will be required? Thanks again for your help in advance.

Comment: @strcompnice, What changes do I need to do to the code to make it run when I have values in decimals in column four. For example if I have a value of 1.1 in cell D4 then what modifications will be required? Thanks again for your help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't see your question Josh. Try to Dim minimumValue As Double instead of Long.